# Using 2 GPU at same time for different traning's TensorFlow\Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

1. Python 2.7
2. TensorFlow
3. Ubuntu

Hello my dear friends, have question. Is it possible to use multi GPU for training different models at same time? It's not a problem to use them for one training with simply code manipulation, but what if I want try to do 2 of them at the same time with different parameters at same time?
I am sorry, if this question is easy, new in programming and TensorFlow. At guide 
[Using GPU's](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/using_gpu/) I tried to find a question about it, but here is for one process only, as I can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks possible. For your models, you use "with tf.device.." and specify different gpus for different models. And then run both the program and see what happens. I tried with a simple program on different gps, it ran. let us know the output you find.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Tensorflow supports multiple GPUs in the same process. You can use `with tf.device("GPU:1")` to assign operators to GPU 1.